# NHibernate take max date from group by paged

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm having an issue getting NHibernate to perform grouping of paged results. What I'm trying to do from a set of data, get data within a date range, group the filtered set of data by the column SearchTerm and selecting the row with the latest SearchDate. All this while paging the data.

```
var results = _nHibernateSession.Query<SearchLog>()
    .Where(x => x.SearchDate <= DateTime.Now && x.SearchDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))
    .GroupBy(x => x.SearchTerm)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.SearchDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList;

var count = _nHibernateSession.Query<SearchLog>()
    .Where(x => x.SearchDate <= DateTime.Now && x.SearchDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))
    .GroupBy(x => x.SearchTerm)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.SearchDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .Count();

var results = query.ToList();
```

The query generated is this

```
SELECT TOP (20 /* @p0 */) 
       * /* Replacing selects here with star to reduce lines */
FROM   (select search0_.search_id                            as search1_51_,
               search0_.search_term                          as search7_51_,
               search0_.search_date                          as search9_51_
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_sort_row
        from   SearchLog.dbo.SearchLog search0_
        where  search0_.search_dt <= '2017-04-12T11:29:57' /* @p1 */
           and search0_.search_dt >= '2017-03-13T11:29:57' /* @p2 */
        group  by search0_.search_term) as query
WHERE  query.__hibernate_sort_row > 0 /* @p3 */
ORDER  BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

As you can see, it's not generating the SQL to group by other rows and just grouping by SearchTerm which is throwing an error saying "Some column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

**NHibernate Version:** 3.3.3.4001

This is what I'm sorta looking for but with pagination (Skip, Take)

```
SELECT s.*
FROM SearchLog.dbo.SearchLog s
INNER JOIN (SELECT   MAX(id) AS MaxSearchId,
                     search_term
            FROM     SearchLog.dbo.SearchLog
            WHERE    user_id = '123'
              AND    search_dt <= '2017-04-12T12:09:50'
              AND    search_dt >= '2017-03-13T12:09:50'
            GROUP BY search_term) groupeds
ON s.id = groupeds.MaxSearchId
ORDER BY s.search_dt DESC
```

It's worth noting that I want to count the number of results, resulting from the group by clause as well. But, I'm not sure how to do a future with this so that I do 1 DB round trip instead of 2, and is there anyway to make this query more efficient.

**UPDATE**
Here's something I tried but still can't seem to get it working

```
var distinctQuery =
(
    from ds in _nHibernateSession.Query<SearchLog>()
    where ds.UserId == userId.ToString() && ds.SearchDate <= DateTime.Now && ds.SearchDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
    group ds by ds.SearchTerm into g
    select new { NumericalId = g.Max(s => s.NumericalId), SearchTerm = g.Key, SearchDate = g.Max(s => s.SearchDate) }
);

var result = 
(
    from s in _nHibernateSession.Query<SearchLog>()
    join ds in distinctQuery on s.NumericalId equals ds.NumericalId
    select s
).ToArray();
```

I'm getting an error saying that "Specified method is not supported". Am I just trying to do something impossible?

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using? Also, can you share the SQL that you were expecting?

Comment: I updated nHibernate version in my question. Regarding query, I guess I am not sure what to expect yet. I am expecting it to return rows with distinct search terms based on max date

Comment: @RicardoPeres I just updated my question to include what I'm looking for